# Magento - Update existing address programmatically

Tags: magento

I have code written to either create or update an address for customer. Create address is working as expected, however update address is giving me the following SQL error:

> Failed To Set Customer Address Info - SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity
>   constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign
>   key constraint fails (`magedev`.`customer_address_entity`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_CUSTOMER_ADDRESS_ENTITY_PARENT_ID_CUSTOMER_ENTITY_ENTITY_ID`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `customer_entity` (`entity_id`)
>   ON DELETE )

Here's my code:

```
// Determine Address Type
$is_default_billing  = 0;
$is_default_shipping = 0;
$addressType = intval($address_info->AddressType);
if ($addressType >= 0) {
    if ($addressType == 0) {
        $is_default_billing  = 1;
        $is_default_shipping = 1;
    } else if ($addressType == 1) {
        $is_default_billing  = 1;
    } else if ($addressType == 2) {
        $is_default_shipping = 1;
    }
}

// Parse Address Data
$address_data = array(
    'firstname'           => $address_info->Firstname,
    'lastname'            => $address_info->Lastname,
    'company'             => $address_info->Company,
    'street'              => array(
        0 => $address_info->AddressLine1,
        1 => $address_info->AddressLine2
    ),
    'city'                => $address_info->City,
    'region_id'           => '',
    'region'              => $address_info->Region,
    'postcode'            => $address_info->Postcode,
    'country_id'          => getCountryId($address_info->Country),
    'telephone'           => $address_info->Telephone,
    'is_default_billing'  => $is_default_billing,
    'is_default_shipping' => $is_default_shipping
);

// Anticipate Error
try
{
    // Get Customer Model
    $customAddress = Mage::getModel('customer/address');

    // Address Create Mode
    if ($address_info->QueueAction == 'Create')
    {
        // Create Address
        $customAddress->setData($address_data)
                      ->setCustomerId(intval($address_info->MagentoCustomerId))
                      ->setSaveInAddressBook(true)
                      ->save();
    }

    // Address Update Mode
    else if ($address_info->QueueAction == 'Update')
    {
        // Update Address
        $customAddress->load(intval($address_info->MagentoId));
        $customAddress->setData($address_data)
                      ->save();
    }

    // Resource Clean-Up
    $customAddress = null;

    // Success - Returns Queue Id Back
    API_Response(false, '', $address_info->QueueId);
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    // Error
    API_Response(true, $e->getMessage());
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Most probably you are trying to set an address for a customer that does not exist.
Try this:

```
->setParentId(intval($address_info->MagentoCustomerId))
```

Instead of

```
->setCustomerId(intval($address_info->MagentoCustomerId))
```

Comment: Okay, I set that on my "Update" queue action handler and now i am no longer getting an error - instead a new address is getting created. Why isn't it updating the loaded address?

Comment: Maybe the address with id `intval($address_info->MagentoId)` does not exist